# CSS shorthand for comma separated elements with same parent class?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to get several (but not *all*) elements of the same parent to have the same style.

```css
.red p, .red a, .red h3, .red button { color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="red">
  <p></p>
  <a></a>
  <h3></h3>
  <button></button>
</div>
```

Is there a shorter way than `.red p, .red a, .red h3, .red button { color: red; }`?

Something along the lines of `.red [p, a, h3, button]` (which doesn't work)?

Thanks

Comment: What you're trying to do can be done in [Less](http://lesscss.org/) or [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/), if you don't mind the extra step of having to compile the relevant file to get your CSS file. It'd be something along the lines of `.red { p, a, h3, button { /* your rules */ } }`

Answer (score 6):

The [`:is`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is) pseudo-selector (formerly known as `:matches` or `:any`) is parts of the [selectors level 4 CSS draft spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#matches-pseudo):

```
.red :is(p, a, h3, button) {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Its partially [supported by browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is#Cross-browser_example) using prefixes:

```css
.red :-webkit-any(p, a, h3, button) {
  color: red;
}

.red :-moz-any(p, a, h3, button) {
  color: red;
}

.red :matches(p, a, h3, button) {
  color: red;
}

.red :is(p, a, h3, button) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
  <p>p</p>
  <a>a</a>
  <h3>h3</h3>
  <button>button</button>
  <div>div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: a better view of the support: https://caniuse.com/#search=%3Ais

Comment: Should work comma separated as well, gets rid of the redundant `color: red; cursor: pointer;`

Comment: @AlexG nope, if a browser doesn't support one of these syntax, then the whole rule should be discarded.

Comment: @Kaiido Ah, thanks for clearing that up. Tbh this soludion probably is way less benificial than the standard `.red p, .red a, .red h3, .red button` then.

Comment: @AlexG - `till there's full support for `:is()` it's pretty stupid to write all this blocks by hand. However, `:is` will be supported some day, and right now if you need to use this feature, there are build tools that will generate the compatibility code for you.

Comment: @AlexG Yes, on this I can only agree (moreover when it anyway requires it to get a respectable browser support.

Answer (score 0):

Before `:is` has a better support, you could use the [:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) selector to exclude the elements you don't want to inherit parents style.

Though with multiple elements you would still end up with something like `.red :not(h1):not(a) { }`

```css
.red :not(h1) {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
  <h1>H1</h1>
  <p>P</p>
  <a>A</a>
  <h3>H3</h3>
  <button>BUTTON</button>
</div>
```